# How to bind h:inputText value to custom object

Tags: java, binding, jsf-2

I'm using JSF 2.0 (JEE6, Glassfish 3.1) and stuck with such problem:

I want to bind my h:inputTexts values not just by a simple String or Integer but my object:

```
public class IDX {

int d;
int k;
int w;

IDX(int d, int k, int w) {
    this.d = d;
    this.k = k;
    this.w = w;
}

//getters&setters
...
```

In managed bean I have:

```
private Map<IDX, Object> values; //with getters&setters
```

which is constructed as a HashMap. Now I would like from my JSF page to bind h:inputText value to an object IDX, something like this:

```
....
<h:form>
   ....
   <h:inputText value="#{myBean.values[1,1,1]}" />
   ....
</h:form>
....
```

which obviously doesn't look good. Any ideas? Is it possible or I have to use Strings or Integers only?

Comment: You need a converter for your object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to bind Idx instance to `h:inputText` your managed bean should look as follows-

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {
    private Idx idx; //getter/setter
```

You are gonna need a converter for Idx that converts an instance of Idx to (and from) String. Something as follows -

```
@FacesConverter(forClass=Idx.class)
public class IdxConverter implements Converter {
    public String getAsString(...//provide implementation
    public Object getAsObject(...//provide implementation
```

And in the page -

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.idx}"/>
```

Comment: ok, but I have many inputTexts with different idxes and wanted to to it in some nice way and bind all of them to one Map<IDX, Object>. One way I found is to change my IDX to a String in Map and then at my managed bean convert this strings to IDX.

Comment: What is the functional requirement? From whatever you said, what I understand is that you are trying have a `h:inputText` for each key in the map in your managed bean and that does not make any sense to me till now.

Comment: I would like to bind inputTextes to my custom keys that looks like 1,1,1 or 1,1,2 etc (like in my first code sample). Only requirement is that I have templates prepared that way to implement as jsf pages. But I think easier will be to convert them (I need to do it anyway) and I'll use simple keys instead. Only drawback - it will be harder to read and manage later. Anyway thanks, you helped me a lot!